I am using the BladeRF 2.0 xA4, and I am encountering this problem in GQRX. Any ideas?
I am using WSL with Ubuntu and wanted to test this new SDR with GQRX at the minimum selectable sample rate of 5 Msps. However, the waterfall starts and then crashes. It continues moving downwards, but the display remains distorted with intermittent audio noise when I try to tune to a radio station frequency. Any ideas? Same happens when I connect a HackRF One. When I use GNU Radio in real time to process signals, the same happens. The reason I am using WSL is because I wanted to use GNU Radio, as I counldnt install GNU Radio with conda in Windows.


It seems that WSL 2, specifically the Vmmem process, was using 12GB of my RAM, which affected the performance of GQRX and GNU Radio. I solved the issue by creating a .wslconfig file in my user directory and limiting the RAM to 4GB and the CPU to 1 core. The performance improved, and I was able to choose a higher sample rate without any issues.

It appears that the audio frequency range is limited. Look at the black box in the LLH corner.
Move your mouse cursor into the black area, just above the word Gain. Then, roll your mouse wheel up or down to regain your lower audio frequencies.
As you roll it, the audio frequency scale along the bottom of the window will change.
I use gqrx myself, with an RTL-SDR.
Let us know if that works for you. :-)

Thank you for the tip. I will take it into consideration for future tests.
